# mouseover mouseout not working properly

Tags: jquery

Am trying show a modal on mouse over and close modal on mouse out.
i give class for div and calling it on .hover.

but its like blinking.
open close open close.

why this behavior??

even mouse is inside div its closing .

```
$('.divclass').hover(function(){
  dialog.open()
},
function(){
  dialog.close()
});
```

i use mouse over and mouseneter .. same behavior like blinking..open close...
Why?? any suggesion

Comment: I guess the problem is that as soon as the dialog opens, you indirectly mouse-out.. Don't think you'll be able to fix that. But let me ask one question: If the dialog is modal, why do you want it to disappear on mouseout then?

Comment: i dont want to use dialog..just any box with few contents,.any suggesion for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to try

```
$('.divclass').mouseenter(function() {
  //dialog open
});

$('.divclass').mouseleave(function() {
  //dialog close
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the css specify the dialog box as: `pointer-events: none;`

This prevents the dialog box from interfering with the hover action.

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code if it works

```
 $('.divclass').hover(
        function () {
          dialog.open();  
        },
        function () {
            dialog.close();
        }
    );
```

There is a [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin which is really useful, try if possible

Comment: mouseover of dialog box becomes , mouseoout of intial div block , that is the reason your dialog box is getting closed.